# Anagram-compare two strings

Tags: string, compare, anagram

I am trying to write a function that determines if two strings are anagrams of each other. I give the function two strings that are equal except for case, and it fails, even though I ignore case in my comparison.

Test case:

```
hello
Hello
```

for these input my output is NOT an anagram, but it is an anagram

SOURCE CODE:

```
static boolean isAnagram(String a, String b) {

    char[] a1 = a.toCharArray();
    char[] b1 = b.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(a1);
    Arrays.sort(b1);
    String x = new String(a1);
    String y = new String(b1);   

    int i=0,flag=0;
    while(i < a1.length)
    {
        if(x.equalsIgnoreCase(y)){
            i++;
        }
        else
            return false;   
    }
   return true;
}
```

Comment: cleaned up source code formatting and added a descriptive introduction

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the while loop;

```
 static boolean isAnagram(String a, String b) {

    char []a1= a.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
    char []b1= b.toLowerCase().toCharArray();

    Arrays.sort(a1);
    Arrays.sort(b1);

    String x= new String(a1), y = new String(b1);

    return x.equals(y);

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Check out the below methods for Anagram Check:**

```
/**
 * Java program - String Anagram Example.
 * This program checks if two Strings are anagrams or not
 */
public class AnagramCheck {

/*
 * One way to find if two Strings are anagram in Java. This method
 * assumes both arguments are not null and in lowercase.
 *
 * @return true, if both String are anagram
 */
public static boolean isAnagram(String word, String anagram){       
    if(word.length() != anagram.length()){
        return false;
    }

    char[] chars = word.toCharArray();

    for(char c : chars){
        int index = anagram.indexOf(c);
        if(index != -1){
            anagram = anagram.substring(0,index) + anagram.substring(index +1, anagram.length());
        }else{
            return false;
        }           
    }

    return anagram.isEmpty();
}

/*
 * Another way to check if two Strings are anagram or not in Java
 * This method assumes that both word and anagram are not null and lowercase
 * @return true, if both Strings are anagram.
 */
public static boolean iAnagram(String word, String anagram){
    char[] charFromWord = word.toCharArray();
    char[] charFromAnagram = anagram.toCharArray();       
    Arrays.sort(charFromWord);
    Arrays.sort(charFromAnagram);

    return Arrays.equals(charFromWord, charFromAnagram);
}


public static boolean checkAnagram(String first, String second){
    char[] characters = first.toCharArray();
    StringBuilder sbSecond = new StringBuilder(second);

    for(char ch : characters){
        int index = sbSecond.indexOf("" + ch);
        if(index != -1){
            sbSecond.deleteCharAt(index);
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    return sbSecond.length()==0 ? true : false;
}
```

}